# How can I reduce the debugging overhead from non-exceptional exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-debugging

We are using an API which heavily relies on exceptions for returning non-exceptional results. An example of this (out of many) is that to ascertain whether a user is in a group of people, we have to attempt to get the group and interpret the resultant "no group" exception. Furthermore, all these exceptions are of one type.

We are working on a large and complex project using C++11 which is heavily multi-threaded, furthermore the area we are working on concerns network communication, so at points we have to debug multiple instances concurrently.

Our problem, and so the basis of my question, arises because of the impact non-exceptional exceptions have on our workflow. We are reticent to turn off the first-chance exception reporting for the single exception type that is thrown by the API because it will mean that if we have a call to the API for which a coder has missed a try/catch block we will unwind to main and loose the context of the call. If we leave the exceptions on then simple non-exceptional behaviour, such as that described in the example above, can result in multiple breaks (the initial throw and potentially some rethrows), and we can only verify that this is in fact a non-exceptional exception by querying the stack, often of a non-main thread, to find the API call which precipitated the exception.

I believe our use case is not so unique that others will not have experienced the same workflow issues, and so my question is how should we alter our debugging process in order to better cope with the issues posed by non-exceptional exceptions, as described above.

We are currently restricted to using Visual Studio (or potentially WinDbg) for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing exceptions in a non-exceptional use case is plain wrong imo. Next step: Every function is `void`, everything gets returned by throwing exceptions.

As far as I understand you are using a thirdparty API that shows this odd behavior. Here's what I normally consider when dealing with an "Odd API" of any kind, including C-APIs that pollute everything with silly macros (yes, I look at you, WinAPI):

1. Try to avoid the parts that behave odd. In your case: if there are nonthrowing checks you can call, do it, i.e. call `if(hasGroup) getGroup; else ...` instead of `try {getGroup;} catch(X) {...}`
2. Instead of letting the oddness ripple through all your code, constrain it by writing a wrapper API. In your case: write a wrapper that catches the Exceptions and translates them in normal return values. That way your coders can't forget to catch normal-case-exceptions (because your wrapper does not throw them), and if you put the wrapper in its own library you might be able to use another exception policy inside the wrapper API. Quick example for your getGroup Problem:

   ```
   //myAPIWrapper.h

   namespace myAPIWrapper {

     class Group;

     class User {
     public:
       boost::optional<Group> getGroup();
     };

   }


   //myAPIWrapper.cpp

   #include "OddAPI.h"

   namespace myAPIWrapper {

     boost::optional<Group> User::getGroup()
     {
       boost::optional<Group> theGroup;

       try {
         oddAPI::user& oddUser= unwrap(*this);
         oddAPI::group& oddGroup = oddUser.get_group();
         theGroup = wrap(oddGroup);
       }
       catch(oddAPI::exception&) {
       }

       return theGroup;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no alternative calls, the whole API uses exceptions and the example I have given is illustrative of this (i.e., the only way to know you are not in a group is by causing an exception). The wrapper suggestion is certainly something we have considered, and may be the closest thing to a solution, but would require a lot of boilerplate code, and would ultimately not remove the risk of missing an exception. I should probably mention, this isn't a little API by a small company, I can't name them, but I suspect you can guess.

Comment: To put it another way, your example is essentially what we're doing, try to catch exceptions at the border between our code and the API, but there is always a potential to miss them, and so it does not allow us to turn off first-chance exceptions, and so does not help our workflow.

Comment: "there is always a potential to miss them" sounds like you are often adding new calls to the API. If you define an interface with everything you are likely to need from that API and implement it with an exception-free wrapper, you will need to write the boilerplate once and are done without the risk of missing an exception. If you further provide exhaustive unit tests for the wrapper (which imo always helps) you can make sure it in fact *is* exception-free. Maybe one single person should be in charge to maintain the wrapper, so the others need not bother with catching exceptions at all.

Comment: That's essentially what we're having to do, but I don't really see the benefit of a unit test. Either each function has a try/catch or it doesn't. In order to say, exhaustively, that it was safe enough to 'not bother catching exceptions' you would have to know enough about the workings of the API to ensure you simulated every internal code path, and even then - to what end?

Comment: You won't have to simulate every internal code path. That's not what abstraction, encapsulation and wrapping is about, and it's not what unit tests are about, either. Simulate the wrapper calls you are going to use, in order to make sure your wrapper works as intended, including it's non-throwing behavior. *That* is what unit tests are about, independent of if you are wrapping a thirdparty API or writing a business logic class or whatever.

Comment: Here's a simple example of why that's wrong. I can 'simulate' a call to StrokeDog(), but whether the dog is there to stroke is not exposed (in fact, I don't even know if there actually is a dog, perhaps it's just inferred from some other state). Therefore if I follow your advice and happen to 'test' it when the dog is there, I happily conclude I can get no exceptions. In production code, I then find in certain circumstances the dog must not be there because I get a exception for 'NoDog', which I was previously unaware of, and my application crashes.